# What movie am I?

Tags: riddle, mathematics, pattern, movies

The grid below contains the first part of a movie quote.

What is the full 46-word quote, and what is the movie?

[image]

Hint #1:

> The movie was very mainstream and was released in the last 10 years.

Hint #2

> The first 4 words of the quote can be figured out from the grid, and then Google is your friend.

Hint #3:

> There are 385 hints in the grid itself.

Hint #4:

> I would consider this the perfect movie quote.

Hint #5:

> The ten letters needed for the first 4 words of the quote are organized in a certain pattern.

Comment: "Contains" as in a word search puzzle?

Comment: @Mauris not in the traditional sense

Comment: are the words in straight lines? do you form them by traversing adjacent tiles? diagonal? are we even looking for words? lol

Comment: The letters that form the 4 words are placed in order on special tiles. Once you find those four words, you have solved 99% of the puzzle, as long as you have a search engine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The four words are :

> Then I saw it

The pattern is :

> Take the first letter which is T. Then the subsequent letters are present at a gap of 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16 and 18 letters. Which is also at each perfect square (1, 4, 9, 16...)

The complete quote is :

> Then I saw it. I saw a Mom who would die for her son; a man who would kill for his wife; a boy, angry and alone, laid out in front of him the bad path. I saw it. And the path was a circle, round and round. So I changed it.

From the movie :

> [Looper](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Looper_(film))

Comment: Actually, the letters are at perfect squares: 1, 4, 9, 16, etc.  It just so happens that the gaps between perfect squares form an increasing sequence.

Comment: Yes. The letters are placed at perfect squares.

Comment: I had originally seen this exact pattern (starting with "THENIS"), but failed to count properly and ended up with nonsense so I gave up. Haha

Comment: +1 Nice job! I guess the hints didn't help you. It seems like you just figured out the pattern, since the gaps are increasing? Wow, impressive. I was hinting at squares, since there are 385 squares in a 10x10 grid. Also, I used the word perfect to describe the quote, hinting at perfect squares.

Comment: @Ian Stick with it next time!